# php array with random amount

Tags: php, arrays

I want to make an array with a random amount of values between 2 and 5.

Each value would be 50.

What's the easiest way to do this?

eg:

```
$array = array(50,50,50,50)
$array = array(50,50)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$array = array();
for($i = 0, $max = rand(2,5); $i < $max; $i++) $array[] = 50;
```

This will create an array with 2 to 5 items with the value 50.

Edit: An easier solution is to use [`array_fill()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill.php):

```
$array = array_fill(0, rand(2, 5), 50);
```

Answer (score 2):

`$array = array_fill(0,rand(2,5), 50)` is the simplest I can think of.

Answer (score 2):

Try with:

```
$array = array_fill(0, rand(2, 5), 50);
```

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at [mt_rand()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php).  To generate a random number between 2 and 5 (inclusive):

```
$random = mt_rand(2, 5);
```

Comment: @TimWolla: Why the -1?  Not coding it for him does not mean my answer is not helpful to him, or others reading this.

Comment: In my opinion this is not helpful enough. Simple as that.

Comment: @TimWolla: In my opinion, you're missing the point of a +1/-1 system if you think "not helpful enough" warrants a -1.  Just don't vote on it at all if it's "not helpful enough."  It's not incorrect, and not bad advice, and it could be helpful to others.  Simple as that.

Comment: Seems like you are right. But sadly I can no longer remove the downvote :/